# Gradle DuplicatesStrategy: in which order are duplicates are checked and resolved when a duplicate is in the local repository?

Tags: gradle, duplicates

I'm reading the documentation for the INCLUDE and EXCLUDE strategies:

EXCLUDE: Do not allow duplicates by ignoring subsequent items to be created at the same path.
INCLUDE: Do not attempt to prevent duplicates.

I'm going to assume that the order of the duplicates in the dependencies is the same order you see in the code, but what about the duplicate in the local repository? When does it get checked? Is it the first one? The last one?